# Debian Squeeze Hyper-V Drivers

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a fresh Debian 6.0.0 (Squeeze) server running on Hyper-V and I'm trying to get the synthetic drivers loaded into the kernel (2.6.32-5-amd64). The research I've done says that the Linux Integration Drivers should have been mereged into the .32 and greater kernel tree but I can't seem to find them in the normal */lib/modules/2.6.32.5-amd64/kernel/* directory. A modprobe also fails to locate and load the modules into the kernelspace.

I'm looking for the following kernel modules:

- hv_vmbus
- hv_blkvscb
- hv_netvsc
- hv_storvsc

Does anyone know where I can find the kernel moduels for the Hyper-V Linux Intergration Drivers? Have they been moved to their own package? Do I need to recomplile the kernel and manually build them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `grep CONFIG_HYPERV /boot/config-2.6.32-5-amd64` shows `CONFIG_HYPERV is not set`.  It appears that Debian has chosen not to build those modules.  I am reading about it, several articles mention hv not being well supported by MS, and some people want to drop it.

I looked and the hv source is present in the 2.6.32 kernel source package (drivers/staging/hv).  One thing you could do is install the kernel source package and the kernel-package tool.  (`apt-get install apt-get install linux-source-2.6 libncurses-dev kernel-package`) Extract the source, copy /boot/config-2.6.32-5-amd64 to .config, use `make menuconfig` and enable the hyperv drivers.  Then compile your kernel with `make-kpkg`.

For kernels with version >3.0 the drivers are no more located in staging. The new locations a described here:
http://dietrichschroff.blogspot.de/2013/03/hyper-v-compile-linux-kernel-with.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does look like the Hyper-V modules are unfortunately not compiled in the default Debian Squeeze kernel. While I'm no strange to rebuilding the kernel, I'd rather not do it on a production machine unless the benefits outweigh the costs (and in this case they may not).

Comment: It seems like it should be possible to recompile the modules without recompiling the entire kernel.  I know both virtual box and vmware does permit you to compile the modules without rebuilding the kernel.  I am not sure how to do that though.

Comment: For me, I get a kernel panic after each reboot unless I always remove the entry for the synthetic network card from `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

Comment: I get kernel error during startup using 2.6.36 with HV modules, anyone solved this trouble? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get Hyper-V modules install on fresh Debian 6 in Hyper-V you need to compile your own kernel. This is how i did it

http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?ref=Internal&from=ru&to=en&a=http://blogs.technet.com/b/abeshkov/archive/2011/03/17/hyperv_5f00_debian.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/abeshkov/archive/2011/03/17/hyperv_5f00_debian.aspx

I think it is also applicable to Debian 5 and bunch of Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to have some moderate success with network drivers, but only when the vm was created on a hyperv console, not scvmm.  In HyperV, selecting "Legacy Adapter" for network adapter type works.. I was able to get tcp connectivity to my vm.  I did not stress the connectivity, or test it's stability, but it worked out of the box.  I found a link on the web that gave me this method (currently uncited, but I'm sure you can find it..)

My version of scvmm does not list "Legacy Adapter" as  a network cary type, however, so I can't get it to work without sideloading a driver after install.

Just for your notes..

Answer (score 0):

Just as reminder: I have been playing with the Hyper-V modules for linux starting 2.6.33 and had freakingly bad results with hv module back these days. If you are using a mainline kernel, you get better results starting 2.6.39 where lots of changes whent in to get them quite stable.

I discourage anyone using hyper-v modules from mainline kernel in older kernels. The notable exception are the MS-provided ones for RHEL and SLES which are backports of later versions and work quite well.

Answer (score -1):

more simple http://docs.homelinux.org/doku.php?id=using_linux_ic_with_debian_squeeze ;)

Comment: It's generally considered very poor form to post link-only answers on ServerFault. Please provide an explanation why you think your answer is appropriate and/or a summary of the information within the link. Answers that remain link-only may be removed by the moderators at their discretion.