# How to get Linux udev to play nice with Hyper-V IC synthetic network driver

Tags: linux, networking, debian, virtualization, hyper-v

I managed to get the Debian 6.0.1 to work with the Microsoft Hyper-V synthetic drivers, thanks to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/240382/debian-squeeze-hyper-v-drivers). However, if I don't remove the entry for the synthetic ethernet card from `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` on every boot, the VM won't boot the next time as there is a `kernel BUG at mm/mmap.c:2129` (Recursive fault) - `last sysfs file: /sys/devices/vmbus_0_0/vmbus_0_3/net/eth0/uevent`

How do I fix this?

**EDIT**:

`75-persistent-net-generator.rules` looks like this:

```
# These rules generate rules to keep network interface names unchanged
# across reboots and write them to /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.

# variables used to communicate:
#   MATCHADDR           MAC address used for the match
#   MATCHID             bus_id used for the match
#   MATCHDRV            driver name used for the match
#   MATCHIFTYPE         interface type match
#   COMMENT             comment to add to the generated rule
#   INTERFACE_NAME      requested name supplied by external tool
#   INTERFACE_NEW       new interface name returned by rule writer

ACTION!="add",                          GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="net",                       GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"

# ignore the interface if a name has already been set
NAME=="?*",                             GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"

# device name whitelist
KERNEL!="eth*|ath*|wlan*[0-9]|msh*|ra*|sta*|ctc*|lcs*|hsi*", \
                                        GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"

# ignore Xen virtual interfaces
SUBSYSTEMS=="xen",                      GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"

# ignore UML virtual interfaces
DRIVERS=="uml-netdev",                  GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"

# ignore "secondary" raw interfaces of the madwifi driver
KERNEL=="ath*", ATTRS{type}=="802",     GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"

# ignore "secondary" monitor interfaces of mac80211 drivers
KERNEL=="wlan*", ATTRS{type}=="803",    GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"

# by default match on the MAC address and interface type
ENV{MATCHADDR}="$attr{address}"
ENV{MATCHIFTYPE}="$attr{type}"

# match interface dev_id
ATTR{dev_id}=="?*", ENV{MATCHDEVID}="$attr{dev_id}"

# These vendors are known to violate the local MAC address assignment scheme
# Interlan, DEC (UNIBUS or QBUS), Apollo, Cisco, Racal-Datacom
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="02:07:01:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# 3Com
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="02:60:60:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# 3Com IBM PC; Imagen; Valid; Cisco; Apple
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="02:60:8c:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# Intel
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="02:a0:c9:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# Olivetti
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="02:aa:3c:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# CMC Masscomp; Silicon Graphics; Prime EXL
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="02:cf:1f:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# Prominet Corporation Gigabit Ethernet Switch
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="02:e0:3b:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# BTI (Bus-Tech, Inc.) IBM Mainframes
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="02:e6:d3:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# Realtek
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="52:54:00:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# Novell 2000
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="52:54:4c:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# Realtec
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="52:54:ab:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"
# Kingston Technologies
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="e2:0c:0f:*", GOTO="globally_administered_whitelist"

# ignore interfaces with locally administered or null MAC addresses
# and KVM and VMWare virtual interfaces
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="?[2367abef]:*",        ENV{MATCHADDR}=""
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="00:00:00:00:00:00",    ENV{MATCHADDR}=""
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="00:0c:29:*|00:50:56:*", ENV{MATCHADDR}=""
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="52:54:00:*|54:52:00:*", ENV{MATCHADDR}=""

LABEL="globally_administered_whitelist"

# ibmveth interfaces have stable locally administered MAC addresses
SUBSYSTEMS=="ibmveth",                  ENV{MATCHADDR}="$attr{address}"

# S/390 interfaces are matched only by id
#SUBSYSTEMS=="ccwgroup", \
#       ENV{MATCHDRV}="$driver", ENV{MATCHID}="$id", ENV{MATCHADDR}=""

# terminate processing if there are not enough conditions to create a rule
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="", ENV{MATCHID}=="", ENV{INTERFACE_NAME}=="", \
                                        GOTO="persistent_net_generator_end"


# provide nice comments for the generated rules
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", \
 ENV{COMMENT}="PCI device $attr{vendor}:$attr{device}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="pcmcia", \
 ENV{COMMENT}="PCMCIA device $attr{card_id}:$attr{manf_id}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", \
 ENV{COMMENT}="USB device 0x$attr{idVendor}:0x$attr{idProduct}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="ccwgroup", \
 ENV{COMMENT}="S/390 device at $id"
SUBSYSTEMS=="ibmveth", \
 ENV{COMMENT}="LPAR virtual device at $id"
SUBSYSTEMS=="ieee1394", \
 ENV{COMMENT}="Firewire device $attr{host_id}"
ENV{COMMENT}=="", \
 ENV{COMMENT}="Unknown $env{SUBSYSTEM} device ($env{DEVPATH})"
ATTRS{driver}=="?*", \
 ENV{COMMENT}="$env{COMMENT} ($attr{driver})"


# ignore interfaces without a driver link like bridges and VLANs, otherwise
# generate and write the rule
DRIVERS=="?*", IMPORT{program}="write_net_rules"

# rename the interface if requested
ENV{INTERFACE_NEW}=="?*", NAME="$env{INTERFACE_NEW}"

LABEL="persistent_net_generator_end"
```

Comment: Currently, I am doing this by deleting the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules`, but I'm looking for a more _correct_ way of doing this?

Comment: What's the contents of 75-persistent-net-generator.rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think try this, based on [a Debian forum post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=61077)

```
mkdir /lib/udev/rules.d/disabled 
mv /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/disabled 
mv /lib/udev/rules.d/75-cd-aliases-generator.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/disabled 
rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/70*
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I have already done - just wondering if there is a way to actually _fix_ the broken script. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: It sounds like the root of the problem is related to Hyper-v generating different device IDs on each reboot, odd.

Answer (score 0):

In your file:

```
# ignore interfaces with locally administered or null MAC addresses
# and KVM and VMWare virtual interfaces
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="?[2367abef]:*",        ENV{MATCHADDR}=""
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="00:00:00:00:00:00",    ENV{MATCHADDR}=""
```

You need to add your mac address to the bottom of this section.  You probably only need to specify the first 3 so something like this:

```
# ignore interfaces with locally administered or null MAC addresses
# and KVM and VMWare virtual interfaces
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="?[2367abef]:*",        ENV{MATCHADDR}=""
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="00:00:00:00:00:00",    ENV{MATCHADDR}=""
ENV{MATCHADDR}=="MS:ma:c9:*", ENV{MATCHADDR}=""
```